# Pass array as get parameters in RoR using HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I have a rails api endpoint that takes an array as one of it's parameters. In rspec I have the following test

```
it 'should get a list of cars' do
  car_ids = [1,2]
  get :index, {car_ids: car_ids, format: :json}
end
```

and in the controller I have verified that

```
params[:car_ids] == [1,2]
```

However, when I use HTTParty to hit this endpoint, the ids in the arrays are Strings, not Integers.

```
prams[:car_ids] == ["1", "2"]
```

Here is my HTTParty call

```
HTTParty.get('api_endpoint', query: {car_ids: [1,2]})
```

I have tried a bunch of variations of this request, such as adding `{format: :json}`, and setting the `content-type` and `accept` headers but to no avail.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You might want to run this once you receive the data: `["1", "2"].map {|i| i.to_i}`

Comment: But of course only if you are sure that in every case it is returning a string value otherwise it will become redundant.

Comment: Can you try changing `query` to `body` and see if that works for you?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the body of an HTTP request is only read when using the POST action.